# Creating a Form inside a non-winforms application

Tags: c++, winforms

I have been working on a opengl engine and I know want to be able to use winforms to manipulate some objects inside it.

What can I do/change to let my application use winforms.
I created a win32 Console application originally.

(Or should I just create a winforms application and do the inverse of my question?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are opened for solutions, the simplest way would be to create an MFC application and host a WinForms user control in it. See [Using a Windows Form User Control in MFC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ahdd1h97.aspx).

An alternative for hosting WinForms in a Win32 application is to use COM interop. Basically you'd expose some of your managed code to COM interop and that would create the form or user control in managed code. See [Hosting WinForm and WPF user controls in Win32 form via COM Interop](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bf2bd138-7f8c-4355-ab4e-544551d20c32/hosting-winform-and-wpf-user-controls-in-win32-form-via-com-interop?forum=wpf).